# Strange "Exception in Tkinter callback" while using canvas

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

```
from tkinter import *
import math
# ---------------------------- CONSTANTS ------------------------------- #
PINK = "#e2979c"
RED = "#e7305b"
GREEN = "#9bdeac"
YELLOW = "#f7f5dd"
FONT_NAME = "Courier"
WORK_MIN = 25
SHORT_BREAK_MIN = 5
LONG_BREAK_MIN = 20

# ---------------------------- TIMER RESET ------------------------------- # 

# ---------------------------- TIMER MECHANISM ------------------------------- # 
def start_timer():
    count_down(5*60)

# ---------------------------- COUNTDOWN MECHANISM ------------------------------- # 
def count_down(count):
    count_min = math.floor(count/60)
    count_sec = count % 60
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{count_min}:{count_sec}")
    if count > 0:
        window.after(1000, count_down, count-1)

# ---------------------------- UI SETUP ------------------------------- #
window = Tk()
window.title("Pomodoro")
window.config(padx=100, pady=50, bg=YELLOW)

canvas = Canvas(width=200, height=224, bg=YELLOW, highlightthickness=0)
tomato_img = PhotoImage(file="tomato.png")
canvas.create_image(100,112, image=tomato_img)
timer_text= canvas.create_text(100,130,text="00:00",fill="white",font=(FONT_NAME, 35, "bold"))
canvas.grid(column=1,row=1)

timer_text= Label(text="Timer", font=(FONT_NAME,50,"bold"),fg=GREEN,bg=YELLOW)
timer_text.grid(column=1,row=0)

start_button = Button(text="Start",font=("Arial",12),highlightthickness=0,command=start_timer)
start_button.grid(column=0,row=2)
reset_button = Button(text="Reset",font=("Arial",12),highlightthickness=0)
reset_button.grid(column=2, row=2)

checkmark = Label(text="✔️",bg=YELLOW,font=(10),fg=GREEN)
checkmark.grid(column=1,row=3)

window.mainloop()
```

so i was trying to put updated timer over my canvas. once i press start the program crashs.
here is the complete error

```
Exception in Tkinter callback                                                                                                               
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1948, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "f:\Programming\python\255 pomodoro-start\main.py", line 17, in start_timer
    count_down(5*60)
  File "f:\Programming\python\255 pomodoro-start\main.py", line 23, in count_down
    canvas.itemconfig(timer_text, text=f"{count_min}:{count_sec}")
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2959, in itemconfigure
    return self._configure(('itemconfigure', tagOrId), cnf, kw)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.752.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1692, in _configure
    self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression
```

Comment: you cant configure a `Label` with `itemconfigure` on a canvas. You have overwritten the name `timer_text` from a canvas text item to a Label.

Comment: Do a preliminary debugging by yourself. The stack trace clearly says you passed invalid arguments to ```canvas.itemconfig()``` at line 23.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> so i was trying to put updated timer over my canvas. once i press
> start the program crashs. here is the complete error

You have two duplicates attributed to `timer_text =` for `Canvas` and `Label`. That error was caused by this _`tkinter.TclError: invalid boolean operator in tag search expression.`

Either select `Canvas` or `Label`. Actually I set for `Label`.

Change this in line 38:

```
timer_text= Label(text="Timer",...
```

to:

```
timer_lbl= Label(text="Timer", ...
```

Screenshot:

[image]